# how to replace a word after three slash with another word?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, indexof

I have one string in which I need to replace one word with another word. Here is my String `clientId` as `/qw/ty/s11/dc3/124` and I have another string `id` as `p13`. I want to replace `s11` in `clientId` String with `p13`.

Format of `clientId` is going to be exactly same always. Meaning there will be three slah `/` always after which I need to replace that word with another word so any word after three slashes, I need to replace it with value of `id`.

```
String clientId = "/qw/ty/s11/dc3/124";
String id = "p13";
String newId = ""; // this should come as /qw/ty/p13/dc3/124
```

What is the easy way to do this?

Comment: I suggest using [`Regular Expressions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Can you provide an example how can I use `regex` here?

Comment: Is clientId always after third slash ?

Comment: yes it is always after third slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely change any part of string with help of regex.

Try:

```
String content = "/qw/ty/xx/dc3/124";
String replacement = "replacement";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:/[^/]+){2}/)([^/]*)(\\S*)", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(content);
if(matcher.find()){
    String result = matcher.replaceFirst("$1" + replacement + "$3");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Based on input string and replacement value, it will emit:

```
/qw/ty/replacement/dc3/124
```

Comment: How should I change the regex to get it work for strings like content = "/qw/ty//dc3/124"?

Comment: @Yev good question and thanks for enlightening. I haven't thought about this possibility but it's easy to adapt it. Simply replace `([^/]+)` with `([^/]*)` and you are good to go.

Comment: thank you, regex seems to be a thing every programmer has to deal with :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indexOf` method to search for the second slash. You would have to do that 3 times. And the 3 position returned would be the one you want. Since you are saying the position never changes, that would be a scenario how to do it. Another way would be to split the string with the `split` method. Then you would have to iterate through it and replace the third word only. And for each iteration you would also have to use `StringBuilder` to concatenate the `String` in order to get a path back. Those two approaches would be without using REGEX values. The third option would be, like someone suggested, to use REGEX.

Comment: Can you provide an example how can I use `indexOf` here?

Comment: To my opinion, using `indexOf ` is not really well suitable here. `indexOf` returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character (and also uses a for-loop internally to get to it). If the position of 3rd slash never changes, you always know the position (in this example it is 6). Otherwise, using 3 times indexOf could look like `clientId.indexOf('/', clientId.indexOf('/', clientId.indexOf('/')+1)+1)`

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this problem was by looping through the first string until 3 slashes were found, and setting a variable called "start" to the index of the third slash. Next, I looped through from start until another slash was found, and set a variable called "end" to the index. After that, I used the string replace method to replace the substring from start+1 to end with the new id. Here's the code:

```
String clientId = "/qw/ty/s11/dc3/124";
    String id = "p13";
    String newId = "";
    String temporaryID = clientId;
    int slashCounter = 0;
    int start = -1; //Will throw index exception if clientId format is wrong
    int end = -1; //Will throw index exception if clientId format is wrong
    for(int i = 0; i < temporaryID.length(); i++){
        if(temporaryID.charAt(i)=='/') slashCounter++;
        if(slashCounter==3){
            start = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = start + 1; i < temporaryID.length(); i++){
        if(temporaryID.charAt(i)=='/') end = i;
        if(end!=-1) break;
    }
    newId = temporaryID.replace(temporaryID.substring(start+1, end), id);
    System.out.println(newId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to replace the word between 3rd and 4th slash

```
        int counter = 0;
        int start=0;
        int end = clientId.length()-1;
        for (int i = 0; i < clientId.length(); i++) {
            if (clientId.charAt(i) == '/') {
                counter++;
                if (counter == 3) {
                    start = i+1; // find the index of the char after the 3rd slash
                } else if (counter == 4) {
                    end = i; // find the index of the 4th slash
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        String newId = clientId.substring(0, start) + id + clientId.substring(end);
```

Or if you want to replace everything after the 3rd slash:

```
String newId = clientId.substring(0, start) + id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex to find string between third and fourth slash which is your ID and do the replace.

**Regex:** `(\/.*?\/.*?\/).*?\/`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD7hP0/1)**

Comment: @david: Saleem has posted the Java code so I won't repeat it. I hope you can make it work.